# Display custom blocks in magento error?

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, static-block, cms-block, custom-block

I am trying to do custom blocks in magento, for that i have created a cms page called Testpage, and inside the URL Key, i have given c-integration i think this seems to be block id, and status is enabled, inside the content text box i gave a short code like this

```
{{block type="core/template" template="syt/syt_home.phtml"}}
```

In my syt_home.phtml i have given an echo statement, but this is not coming in the front end, i am not sure what i did wrong? also changed the cms home page to cms Testpage in admin side.

Comment: can you post a bit more code please ? Like what have you written in the phtml and do you reference that block somewhere?

Comment: i have changed the syt_home.phtml to c_home.phtml {{block type="core/template" template="syt/c_home.phtml"}} now it is worked, Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

The answer is change syt_home.phtml to

c_home.phtml 
and 
{{block type="core/template" template="syt/c_home.phtml"}}